# Наследование фрагмента в андроид

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть три фрагмента которые отображают погоду:

1. CurrentWeatherFragment - отображает текущую погоду
2. ThreeDaysWeatherFragment - отображает погоду на следующие 3 дня
3. TenDaysWeatherFragment - отображает погоду на следующие 10 дней

Я решил создать родительский фрагмент WeatherFragment для трех моих фрагментов с погодой. Мне нужно чтоб родительский фрагмент содержал в себе BottomNavigationView для трех фрагментов с погодой, но я не могу понять как это сделать. Ничего подходящего в гугле мне найти не удалось, поэтому прошу помощи здесь. Заранее спасибо

WeatherFragment

```
abstract class WeatherFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather, container, false)
    }
```

CurrentWeatherFragment

```
class CurrentWeatherFragment : WeatherFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var currentWeatherFactory: CurrentWeatherFragment
    private lateinit var currentWeatherViewModel: CurrentWeatherViewModel

    private lateinit var weatherDataBinding: CurrentWeatherDataFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        weatherDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            layoutInflater, R.layout.current_weather_data_fragment, container, false
        )

        return weatherDataBinding.root
    }
```

ThreeDaysWeatherFragment

```
class ThreeDaysWeatherFragment : WeatherFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dailyWeatherFactory: DailyWeatherFactory
    private lateinit var dailyWeatherViewModel: DailyWeatherViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three_days_weather, container, false)
    }
```

TenDaysWeatherFragment

```
class TenDaysWeatherFragment : WeatherFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dailyWeatherFactory: DailyWeatherFactory
    private lateinit var dailyWeatherViewModel: DailyWeatherViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ten_days_weather, container, false)
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужно 4 фрагмента. Один с BottomNavigationView и 3 - с погодой. И скорее всего, последние 3 вам наследовать от общего WeatherFragment не нужно - не понятно какую логику туда можно было бы вынести.

Comment: Я бы сделал 1 фрагмент, который определял бы своё поведение в зависимости от того, как его создали (3 дня, 10 дней, неделя, год и тд). Постарайтесь не дублировать одинаковые фрагменты как разные сущности. Логика по идее у них одна, просто разный набор данных

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я так и написал, 3 фрагмента с погодой а четвертый родитель с BottomNavigationView. Логика такая, что BottomNavigationView  у меня был в MainActivity, и он нужен мне только для переключения трех фрагментов с погодой, но у меня есть помимо этих трех фрагментов с погодой еще фрагменты с другой логикой и мне приходится прятать BottomNavigationView  при переходе к одному из них. Я решил убрать BottomNavigationView  из MainActivity и создать фрагмент родителя для трех фрагментов с погодой который и будет содержать BottomNavigationView. Но вот только я не могу понять как это реализовать

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что вы путаете "родительский фрагмент" в двух его возможных в данной ситуации значениях. Первое значение - класс-родитель, который наследуется другими фрагментами и второе - фрагмент, внутри которого - другие фрагменты. Мне кажется, что вам надо второй вариант использовать определения. Прятать вручную как-то нижнюю навигацию не нужно - просто отображайте фрагменты без оного не внутри фрагмента с нижней навигацией, а поверх него.